# Use multiple instances of same polymer custom element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, multiple-instances

I have an issue using polymer (1.3.1) to define a custom element which is a svg button for a Portal webapp.

Here the code of my custom element :

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../lib/polymer/1.3.1/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="portal-button">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="portal-button.css">
  <template>
    <svg id="hexagon-button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="187">
      <a xlink:href="#dummy" xlink:href$="{{url}}">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="dashed-line" height="9" width="9" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="9" height="9" fill="rgb(245,245,245)" />
            <line x1="1" y1="9" x2="9" y2="1" stroke="rgb(187,187,187)" stroke-dasharray="2" />
          </pattern>
          <pattern id="logo" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 135 133">
            <image id="buttonlogo" width="135" height="133" xlink:href="#dummy" xlink:href$="{{src}}" />
          </pattern>
          <pattern id="text" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 590 76">
            <image id="buttontext" width="590" height="76" xlink:href="#dummy" xlink:href$="{{text}}" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <g class="button">
          <g class="back">
            <path d="M 150,13 L 50,13 0,100 50,187 150,187 200,100 z M 140,31 L 60,31 20,100 60,169 140,169 180,100 z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#dashed-line)" />
            <polygon points="140,31 60,31 20,100 60,169 140,169 180,100" fill="rgb(88,151,162)" />
            <polygon points="140,31 60,31 20,100 60,169 140,169 180,100" fill="url(#logo)" />
          </g>
          <g class="front">
            <polygon points="19,100 25,90 175,90 181,100 175,110 25,110" fill="url(#dashed-line)" />
            <polygon points="19,100 25,90 175,90 181,100 175,110 25,110" fill="url(#text)" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </a>
    </svg>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'portal-button',

    properties: {
      text: String,
      url: String,
      src: String
    }
  });
</script>
```

A little bit of css to display/hide the front svg element

```css
.back {
 fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

.front {
 fill-opacity: 0.1;
}

.button:hover > * {
 fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

The index.html with declaration of two instances of my custom element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Izakiel's Lair</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="chaos_symbol.png">
  <!-- include polymer html5 polyfill library -->
  <script src="lib/webcomponentsjs/0.7.21/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="components/portal-button/portal-button.html">
</head>

<body>
  <portal-button id="virtualmin" url="http://localhost:8080/portal" src="img/virtualmin-logo.svg" text="img/virtualmin-titles.svg"></portal-button>
  <portal-button id="jenkins" url="http://localhost:8080/portal" src="img/jenkins-logo.svg" text="img/jenkins-titles.svg"></portal-button>
</body>

</html>
```

When the page is loaded the rendering is perfectly ok.

[image: page loaded]

When i hover with cursor on a button, the opacity is set to 1 by css, forcing the browser to redraw the button.
When the button is re-rendered, all the information for svg image are rendered with the latest declared element (i.e the jenkins button data in this example) but ll the datas in the DOM are perfectly goods that is weird in my opinion.

[image: after hover]

Does someone know why the browser set all custom elements rendering with latest element rendering or is it a bug ?

My previous test was done with Chrome, when i try with Firefox it's even worst, all the elements have the rendering of the first element, but datas in the DOM are good. Did i miss something ?

[image: firefox example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that the patterns are global, not scoped to the shadow root. I tried this with both shady DOM and native shadow root, with the same results.

Here's a partial workaround that fixes the immediate issue on both Chrome and Firefox: create a unique ID for each pattern:

```
<pattern id="logo-{{id}}" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 135 133">
  <image id="buttonlogo" width="135" height="133" xlink:href="#dummy" xlink:href$="{{src}}" />
</pattern>
```

Apply the pattern like this:

```
<polygon points="140,31 60,31 20,100 60,169 140,169 180,100" fill$="[[_computeFill('#logo', id)]]" />
```

I found I needed a computed binding here--I think the parens in the `url(` arg mixed up the binding system, but perhaps I just got something wrong. YMMV. Anyway, the computing function could look like this:

```
_computeFill: function(name, id) {
  return 'url('+ name + '-' + id + ')';
}
```

You could make this a little more elegant, but this should get you working.

This is a partial workaround because if you re-use an ID, you'll be back to the initial problem of swapping images.

If you wanted to avoid that, you could define a separate library of patterns, identified by ID (like the `iron-iconset-svg` does for icons). Or as a simpler solution,  you could compute a unique ID from the SVG file name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, at least it's not a heavy 'fixaround' :), do you think i should open an issue on Polymer Github repository ?

Comment: I managed to reproduce this issue (or a close variant) without using Polymer, just the generic web components APIs. After consulting with some folks on the Chrome team, I think this is a Chrome bug, and I've filed it here: [issue 579080](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597080).